# Filtrando filas de un dataframe en base a los valores de otro dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo los siguientes dataframes:

**df1**

```
start_date,end_date,pollster,sponsor,sample_size,population,party,subject,tracking,text,approve,disapprove,url
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,42,29,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,376,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,75,6,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,523,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,21,51,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,599,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,25,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",2200,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,57,22,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",684,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,88,4,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",817,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,37,37,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",700,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,50,22,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,1996,rv,all,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",39,35,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,700,rv,R,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",71,8,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,788,rv,D,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",15,60,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,508,rv,I,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",34,33,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-09,2020-02-11,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,28,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/79zfxkws33/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-09,2020-02-11,YouGov,Economist,378,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,74,7,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/79zfxkws33/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-09,2020-02-11,YouGov,Economist,510,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,19,50,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/79zfxkws33/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-09,2020-02-11,YouGov,Economist,607,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,33,25,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/79zfxkws33/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-16,2020-02-18,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,32,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/m3wzkd0n59/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-16,2020-02-18,YouGov,Economist,381,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,78,8,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/m3wzkd0n59/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-16,2020-02-18,YouGov,Economist,529,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,11,59,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/m3wzkd0n59/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-16,2020-02-18,YouGov,Economist,583,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,36,25,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/m3wzkd0n59/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-23,2020-02-25,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,31,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/zye3phsf7t/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-23,2020-02-25,YouGov,Economist,386,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,77,7,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/zye3phsf7t/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-23,2020-02-25,YouGov,Economist,525,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,14,56,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/zye3phsf7t/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-23,2020-02-25,YouGov,Economist,588,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,34,26,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/zye3phsf7t/econTabReport.pdf
continua.......
```

**df2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
continua...
```

Hasta el momento he importado los datasets como dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(path)
df2 = pd.read_excel(path2)
```

Además he aplicado las siguientes condiciones de acuerdo con los requerimientos:

```
newdf1 = df1[df1["tracking"] == "FALSE"]
newdf2 = df2[df2["Banned by 538"] == "no"]
```

Además de esto, quiero que el `df1` solo contenga las filas por las que el valor de la columna `pollster` existe en el `df2`. En este sentido, si `pollster` toma el valor "Morning Consult", "Morning Consult" también deberá aparecer en Pollster del `df2`. En caso contrario, la fila en el df1 será eliminada. Cómo podria hacer esto?

Comment: Quieres que el resultado final del dataframe1 solo contenga los datos que tiene el daraframe2 ?

Comment: No. Quiero que solo se mantengan las filas del df1 que tienen un valor que exista en el df2. Es decir, si el valor de pollster existe en df1 y en df2 mantendremos la lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple creo, es trabajar la columna del segundo dataframe como un `set` y usar el verbo [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin):

```
df1[df1['pollster'].isin(set(df2['pollster']))]
```